# Homology connected sum of tori

Tags: algebraic-topology

I want to understand how we computed the homology of the connected sum of tori in class. So let $\Sigma_g$ be a connected sum of tori. $Y$ a single torus, from which one has cut a 2-disk. Then $\Sigma_g/Y \cong \Sigma_{g-1}$. We assume that we know the $k$th homology of Y (0 if k $\not =$ 1, $\mathbb{Z}$ if k=1).

Via induction:

(1) 0, 1 are clear.

(2) Induction step $g-1 \to g$.

We use the long exact sequence of the good pair $(\Sigma_g, Y)$

$... \to \tilde{H}_{k+1}(\Sigma_{g-1}) \to \underbrace{\tilde{H}_{k}(Y)}_{=0, ~k\not=1} \to \tilde{H}_{k}(\Sigma_{g}) \to \underbrace{\tilde{H}_{k}(\Sigma_{g-1})}_{=0, ~k\not=1,2 (IA)} \to ...$

So for $k \not= 1,2: \tilde{H}_{k}(\Sigma_{g})=0$.

For k=1,2:

$... \to \underbrace{\tilde{H}_{2}(Y)}_{=0} \xrightarrow{i} \tilde{H}_{2}(\Sigma_{g}) \xrightarrow{j} \underbrace{\tilde{H}_{2}(\Sigma_{g-1})}_{\mathbb{Z}~~(IA)} \xrightarrow{\partial} \underbrace{\tilde{H}_{1}(Y)}_{= \mathbb{Z}^2} \xrightarrow{\phi} \tilde{H}_{1}(\Sigma_{g}) \xrightarrow{\psi} \underbrace{\tilde{H}_{1}(\Sigma_{g-1})}_{= \mathbb{Z}^{2g-2}~~(IA)} \to ...$

Exactness yields ker(j) = im(i) = 0, so j is injective.

If I could show now that j is also surjective, then j would be an iso and so $\tilde{H}_{2}(\Sigma_{g}) \cong \mathbb{Z}$. Apart from this I can't see how I can show now that $\tilde{H}_{1}(\Sigma_{g}) = \mathbb{Z}^{2g}$. Can someone give me a hint?

Thank you very much and greetings,

Aceras

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\partial_1 =0$ or equivalently $\phi$  is injective. Also $\partial_0=0$ equivalently $\psi$ is onto. Hence you have a splitting short exact sequence. So (as very often with long exact sequences) the problem boils down to filling in  zeros (zero maps) (or appropriately modifying the sequence).

If you know that the surface is orientable and admits a cellular decomposition with a single $0$-cell and $2$-cell respectively, then you have a chain complex

$$
0 \to \mathbb Z \stackrel 0\to \mathbb Z^{2g} \stackrel 0\to \mathbb Z \to 0.
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I can't see why \partial_1 = 0. Is there a concrete formulare for this boundary or how do you see that it is 0?